# Windows 8.1 lock screen delay

Tags: windows

I recently got Windows 8.1.
One annoying thing is a delay at the lockscreen.

When the clock and date is displayed (no password entering field yet) I press a key. Usually the first key of my password but it is not entered into the field.
Then the screen slides up and the user picture and password field is displayed.
Then I enter the password.

From pressing a key (to get rid of the clock) to being able to enter something into the password field approximately one second is necessary.

While the clock slides up and is completely hidden no keys can be entered into the password field, so there is a delay of 1 second.

Is it possible to get rid of this delay?

Comment: On my personal machines the transition is nearly instantaneous.  This sounds like a performance problem to me.

Comment: Is 1 sec that much annoying? We waste hours everyday, Man!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a performance issue due to more number of programs in startup, hence some simple steps for optimizing the performance like limiting the the number of programs in startup,  removing unwanted programs may help to fix this issue.

Please go through the below article to optimize the performance and check the results:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/optimize-windows-better-performance#optimize-windows-better-performance=windows-7

Comment: It is not at startup. It is with a booted computer having nothing to do, pressing Win+L. So no performance issue.